# Call derived c++ Mixins with static_cast

Tags: c++

I have an abstract interface class, `ElementInterface`, from which several classes (specific elements) derive. Each one of these classes is constructed from a combination of two unique components (a physics system, and a shape). There is an arbitrary number of shapes and physics, and any combination of them should result in a something conforming to `ElementInterface`. This is because I eventually will iterate through a container of `ElementInterface` objects, and call a few virtual methods on each.

I thought I might approach this problem using run time polymorphism and virtual functions on the interface level, and template-based polymorphism on the Element level. I've come up with solutions that I'm *almost* happy with using both CRTP and Mixin patterns. My Mixin solution is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ElementInterface {
 public:
  virtual void stiffness() = 0;
};

class Acoustic: public ElementInterface {
 public:
  void stiffness() {
    cout << "Computing acoustic stiffness\n";
    gradient();
  }
  virtual void gradient() = 0;
};

class Elastic: public ElementInterface {
 public:
  void stiffness() {
    cout << "Computing elastic stiffness\n";
    gradient();
  }
  virtual void gradient() = 0;
};

template <class Physics>
class QuadP1: public Physics {
  void gradient() {
    cout << "Calculating P1 Jacobian\n";
  }
};

template <class Physics>
class QuadP2: public Physics {
  void gradient() {
    cout << "Calculating P2 Jacobian\n";
  }
};

int main() {
  cout << "Hello world." << endl;
  std::vector<ElementInterface*> vec;
  ElementInterface *acoustic = new QuadP1<Acoustic>;
  ElementInterface *elastic = new QuadP1<Elastic>;
  ElementInterface *elasticp2 = new QuadP2<Elastic>;
  vec.push_back(acoustic);
  vec.push_back(elastic);
  vec.push_back(elasticp2);
  for (auto &e: vec) { e->stiffness(); }
  return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty happy with it, except for the `virtual` label on `gradient()`. At the level at which that function is called, performance is important. I imagine there may be around this though... since I create my elements with `new QuadP1<Acoustic>`, is there a way for the resulting object to know ahead of time which version of `gradient()` to call? Similar to how you might use `static_cast<Derived*> (this)` in the CRTP?

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Ah thanks, you're completely correct in both cases. I've edited the question and removed the CRTP stuff... I think it was just adding noise to the original question anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I can think of which allows you to remove the need for a `virtual` `gradient` function involves type erasure. However, the type erasure comes with a runtime cost and so I don't know if this will actually provide a performance benefit. Regardless, I've provided the example code for illustration.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class ElementInterface
{
public:
    virtual void stiffness() = 0;
};

class Acoustic: public ElementInterface
{
public:
    Acoustic(std::function<void ()> gradient) : mGradientFn(gradient) {}

    void stiffness()
    {
        cout << "Computing acoustic stiffness\n";
        mGradientFn();
    }
    //virtual void gradient() = 0;

private:
    std::function<void ()> mGradientFn;
};

class Elastic: public ElementInterface
{
public:
    Elastic(std::function<void ()> gradient) : mGradientFn(gradient) {}

    void stiffness()
    {
        cout << "Computing elastic stiffness\n";
        mGradientFn();
    }
    //virtual void gradient() = 0;

private:
    std::function<void ()> mGradientFn;
};

template<typename Physics>
class QuadP1 : public Physics
{
public:
    QuadP1() : Physics(std::bind(&QuadP1::gradient, this)) {}

    void gradient()
    {
        cout << "Calculating P1 Jacobian\n";
    }
};

template<typename Physics>
class QuadP2 : public Physics
{
public:
    QuadP2() : Physics(std::bind(&QuadP2::gradient, this)) {}

    void gradient()
    {
        cout << "Calculating P2 Jacobian\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world." << endl;
    std::vector<ElementInterface*> vec;
    ElementInterface *acoustic = new QuadP1<Acoustic>;
    ElementInterface *elastic = new QuadP1<Elastic>;
    ElementInterface *elasticp2 = new QuadP2<Elastic>;
    vec.push_back(acoustic);
    vec.push_back(elastic);
    vec.push_back(elasticp2);
    for (auto &e: vec) { e->stiffness(); }
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/YyB1wX)

Comment: Thanks very much! I hadn't heard of type erasure before. I'll benchmark both for my application, and hopefully (eventually) post the results here.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a virtual constructor may be of use in this scenario?
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor

Comment: Was the downvote really necessary? He did ask for suggestions.